# call `[.data.table` explicitly

Tags: r, data.table

I have a weird behavior, when running my R program on another machine.
When I try to run a data.table join `df1[df2]` I get the error message

> Error in `[.default`(x, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'

I assume that for some reason the R environment on the other machine does not find the data.table bracket function (Although I have loaded the library there).

To force R to use the bracket from data.table I would like to call the bracket function explicitly, but I can't find out how.

Here what I've tried

```
library(data.table)    
df1 <- data.frame(a = c("a1","a2","a3"), n = c(1,2,3), b = c(T,T,T))
df2 <- data.frame(a = c("a1","a2","a3"), n = c(1,2,3), b = c(F,T,F))

df1 <- data.table(df1)
df2 <- data.table(df2)
setkey(df1,a,n,b)
setkey(df2,a,n,b)

df1[df2] # produces `[.default`(x, i) : invalid subscript type 'list'

# my tries to call `[.data.table` explicitly all produce errors
`[.data.table`(df1, df2)
data.table::`[.data.table`(df1, df2)
data.table::`[`(df1, df2)
```

How can I use the bracket function from the data.table package explicitly?

**EDIT:**

OK, I'm trying to find the root cause of the error.
I'm using R version 3.2.1,

```
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2 mypackage_1.0    ROracle_1.1-10   DBI_0.2-7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1    reshape2_1.4  Rcpp_0.11.2   stringr_0.6.2
```

`is.data.table` gives `TRUE` on both, df1 and df2 just before calling `df1[df2]` (I'm debugging through the code).

The function that contains the codeline `df1[df2]` is called inside mypackage_1.0 (A package I'm developing). I have noticed, that if I run the code line by line, instead of calling my package function and debugging it, the code works as expected. So I assume there is something wrong with the package. In the DESCRIPTION file I only import the package data.table under "Suggests". Might it be related to that?

Comment: No, investigate why the error occurs. From the error message I would assume that `df1` is not a data.table. Please provide your `sessionInfo`. (I can't reproduce this on my machine.)

Comment: Also, before running `df1[df2]` (on your real data set), please check what `is.data.table(df1)` gives. I have a feeling you have some typo here. Btw, you can create your `data.table`s and setting the keys directly. Try `df1 <- data.table(a = c("a1","a2","a3"), n = c(1,2,3), b = c(T,T,T), key = "a,n,b")`

Comment: But good effort at *trying* to make a reproducible example. I cannot recreate this error. At a guess maybe you typed `dt1` or `dt2` instead of `df1` or `df2` when creating `data.table` from your `data.frames`. Maybe use the `setDT(df1)` function instead?

Comment: @Roland, David, Simon, thank you for the replies, I have done what you suggested and made an edit to the question.

Comment: Ok, I think the error is something similar to what is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039194/making-a-package-in-r-that-depends-on-data-table I will try to solve it based on this question

Comment: Moving data.table from "Suggests" to "Depends" section of the DESCRIPTION file solved the issue

Comment: Data.table should be in "Imports" (and of course be imported in NAMESPACE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To long for a comment so posting as answer.
General comments related to your case.

1. You can call `[.data.table` explicitly by calling not exported data.table function using `:::` operator.

```
data.table:::`[.data.table`(x, i)
```

Using `:::` is not a best practice, as it makes you responsible for a function which package author decided not to expose to users directly. You should keep that in mind, still the `R CMD check` will not raise an error or warning. According to [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports):

> Using `foo:::f` instead of `foo::f` allows access to unexported objects. This is generally not recommended, as the semantics of unexported objects may be changed by the package author in routine maintenance.

In my opinion if you develop and internal package which will be deployed with explicitly stated version of dependencies, it is pretty safe to use `:::`.

2. Update your data.table version, 1.9.2 is pretty old release already.
3. In your DESCRIPTION file use *Imports* data.table and don't forget to define imports in NAMESPACE file
4. Debug your problematic machine with the following

```
if(is.data.table(df1) && is.data.table(df2)) df1[df2] else stop("not a data.table")
```

5. Use `sessionInfo()` as one of your first step in debugging cross package issues to track attached packagess.

Comment: I will accept this answer, as valid answer to my initial question. Thanks for the additional advise. Please note that I solved my problem by moving data.table from "Suggests" to "Depends" section of the DESCRIPTION file of my package.

Comment: never new about the distinction of `:::`, thanks for the tip