# devtools::test started failing on my package (with X warning) since devtools 1.13.4 and testhat 2.0

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

## I perform a major edit since I managed to narrow down the problem:

I encounter a new problem with devtools::test. My package used to pass unit test without any problem. But after updating my packages (including devtools and testthat) it now fails.

## Reproducible example:

I have managed to build a reproducible example: In a new package architecture.

**foo.R**: a R file in /R/

```
foo <- function(obj){
  return(as.numeric(obj))
}
```

**test_foo.R**: a uniit test file in /tests/testthat

```
test_that("Test my foo function: ",
          {
            expect_true(is.na(foo("1,5")))
            })
```

**testhat.R**: to run my units tests in /tests/

```
library(testthat)
library(foo)
test_check("foo")
```

## Two scenarios

**Running: devtools::test()**

```
> devtools::test()
Loading foo
Loading required package: testthat
Testing foo
√ | OK F W S | Context
Error in x[[method]](...) : attempt to apply non-function

== Results =====================================================================
Duration: 0.1 s

OK:       0
Failed:   4
Warnings: 1
Skipped:  0
```

**Running testtjat::test_dir("tests/")**

```
> testthat::test_dir("tests/")
√ | OK F W S | Context
== testthat results  ===========================================================
OK: 2 SKIPPED: 0 FAILED: 0

== Results =====================================================================
Duration: 0.1 s

OK:       0
Failed:   0
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0
```

## Environement

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] foo_0.0.0.9000 testthat_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.15     roxygen2_6.0.1   rprojroot_1.3-2  crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.0 digest_0.6.14    withr_2.1.1      commonmark_1.4  
 [9] R6_2.2.2         backports_1.1.2  magrittr_1.5     cli_1.0.0        rlang_0.1.6      stringi_1.1.6    rstudioapi_0.7   xml2_1.1.1      
[17] desc_1.1.1       devtools_1.13.4  tools_3.4.3      stringr_1.2.0    yaml_2.1.16      compiler_3.4.3   memoise_1.1.0
```

## NB:

An issue have been open on this matter on Github: https://github.com/hadley/devtools/issues/1675

Comment: This question is 400% too long. Please put a clear succinct description of what the issue is on both the title and the first sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back, but I'm not quite sure on how to improve this question that necessitate to describe how i build muy package. Could you provide some advices?

Comment: Well, *'I encounter a new problem with devtools::test"'* tells us almost nothing. Do you mean *"devtools::test started failing on my package (with X warning) since change Y"*? Or was it always failing? Or did it used to pass before `assertthat 0.2.0/ devtools 1.13.4` or some other package upgrade? (If so, roll back and tell us what package versions are known-good.) You seriously need to define what "I encounter a problem" means. In the first sentence. Also title. If those are unclear, you'll lose 90% of your audience on the first line.

Comment: Move the code to below a clear concise description of the problem. Format it with code formatting. Use horizontal dividers to demarcate code from other section, for legibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a testhat issue, which was also raised on github https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/700.

A solution was to put a `context("some_string")` at the beginning of each test file.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `data.table` in your package, imports data.table in description is not enough. (note it should be `imports`, not `import`)

```
DESCRIPTION
Imports:
    data.table
```

This only ask your package user to have `data.table` package installed.

You will also need to add this

```
NAMESPACE
import(data.table)
```

Usually this is used to write `function` instead of `pkg::function` and is not suggested. However you have to do this for `data.table`.

Below is my explanation but it may not be totally accurate. I think it's because data.table need to dispatch some `data.table` specific functions for the implicit `[]` and other usage, which is not normal function call so you are not using something like `data.table::rbindlist`, and because the object is also a data.frame, the base version is called and caused problem.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33039194/making-a-package-in-r-that-depends-on-data-table/33039379#33039379) is a related question and answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, `imports` was a typo. I managed to narrow my problem down so I edited my question. It has in fact nothing to do with data.table. Sorry.